# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when using FullAjaxExceptionHandler

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I'm trying to use omnifaces' FullAjaxExceptionHandler, but I'm getting `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` at `org.omnifaces.util.Faces.normalizeViewId(Faces.java:312) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]`.

My web.xml file has the following error setup:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/ErroServlet</location>
</error-page>
```

Where `ErroServlet` is my servlet that does the redirect to the right error page, depending on the request url (I have 2 different error pages).

I'm trying to use `FullAjaxExceptionHandler`, so that exception thrown during an ajax request are also treated.

My ErroServlet checks if it's an Ajax request using:

```
private boolean isXMLHttpRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader("Faces-Request"));
}
```

If true, it redirects using:

```
resp.setContentType("text/xml");
resp.getWriter().append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>")
    .printf("<partial-response><redirect url=\"%s\"></redirect></partial-response>", url);
```

As I said, I'm getting a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` after the servlet is done. And also, the page does **not** visually redirect.

Full Stack Trace:

```
11:47:26,435 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/pso]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) An exception occurred during JSF ajax request. Showing error page location '/ErroServlet'.: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:165) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1560) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:380) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1612) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:367) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:138) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:518) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:142) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:303) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:303) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:192) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [primefaces-3.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at br.ind.seat.pso.filtros.FiltroUrlPattern.doFilter(FiltroUrlPattern.java:50) [classes:]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at br.ind.seat.pso.filtros.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:22) [classes:]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at br.ind.seat.pso.filtros.FiltroPesquisaLogado.doFilter(FiltroPesquisaLogado.java:45) [classes:]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]

11:47:26,437 WARN  [org.jboss.solder.exception.control.log] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) No handlers found for exception java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
11:47:26,438 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/pso].[Faces Servlet]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
    at org.omnifaces.util.Faces.normalizeViewId(Faces.java:312) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.handle(FullAjaxExceptionHandler.java:179) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [javax.faces-2.1.9.jar:2.1.9-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [primefaces-3.4.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74) [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at br.ind.seat.pso.filtros.FiltroUrlPattern.doFilter(FiltroUrlPattern.java:50) [classes:]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at br.ind.seat.pso.filtros.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:22) [classes:]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at br.ind.seat.pso.filtros.FiltroPesquisaLogado.doFilter(FiltroPesquisaLogado.java:45) [classes:]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:75) [omnifaces-1.1.jar:1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the `FullAjaxExceptionHandeler` javadoc](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/exceptionhandler/FullAjaxExceptionHandler.html):

> This exception handler will parse the web.xml and web-fragment.xml files to find the error page locations of the HTTP error code 500 and all declared specific exception types. **Those locations need to point to Facelets files.**

A plain servlet location is not supported as it is not possible to create an `UIViewRoot` around it, let alone to render it by JSF `ViewHandler`.

You'd better create a fullworthy Facelets file which includes/renders the request-specific error page content dynamically.

The `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is at its own however a separate bug which is already fixed in latest snapshot of OmniFaces 1.2.

Comment: Thank you. I tought I could point to a servlet that would then point to a Facelet page, but I understood your explanation. All I had to was to change `<ui:composition template="layout.xhtml">` to `<ui:composition template="#{bean.layout}">`, and verify the request URI in postContruct to return the right layout. It's much simpler now. Thank you very much. :)